# Excel 2007 rejecting bold command after conditional formatting is applied

Tags: excel, scripting, automation, excel-2007, autohotkey

I have an AutoHotkey script that is interacting with an Excel (2007) spreadsheet.  It does the following:
Type an entry,
Selectively bold words in entry,
Move to 2nd cell and type another entry,
Move to 3rd cell and stop.

This works perfectly, but the 2nd cell contains conditional formatting that is occasionally triggered by the 2nd entry.  Any time the formatting is triggered, Excel will start rejecting the selective bolding. I have tried using long Sleep and SetKeyDelay times to no avail.

When I do slow test runs it looks like the bold style is applying, and stays after Excel exits 'Edit Mode'.  For some reason it fails at the beginning of "send {right 3} ; go to top 'choice' cell".  I cannot replicate the error with manual input.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?  Thanks!

```
:*:007\::
send XXX!{enter}Hooligan!{enter}007
send {F2}+{left 4}^b ; enter Edit Mode and bold end number
send {left 1}+{left 8}^b{F2} ; bold name and exit Edit Mode
send {right 3} ; go to top 'choice' cell
send {enter} ; down to 'option' cell
send {enter}{right 11} ; down 1, move to code cell
send 999!{enter}XX9999
send {enter}{up 2}{down}{left 14}
return
```

Comment: Solved - Autofill was cloning cells above... Disabled that and it is now working correctly...

Comment: Would you mind writing an answer, it is totally fine to answer your own questions.

Comment: It's not only fine, it's recommended. On SO, instead of changing the question's title, we accept answers in order to let people know that the problem's solved. This way, other people can profit from our solutions, too.

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up.  Still getting used to posting here lol.  It says I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow, so I guess I'll come back to it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Excel's autocomplete function was cloning previous entries and ruining the formatting.  After autofill was disabled, everything started working properly.